# Getting a not defined error with scripts embedded in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a knowledge base for my work. I'm trying to get full html w/scripting setup within a iFrame instance.

Below is a Chrome expansion of my setup. When I click the button in my `div/iframe`, I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined` error.

Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/153274-script-iframe-can-not-call-functions-defined-parent-document

Per link:
Functions are not properties of the document, but of the window.
Try
`parent.foo();`
or
`top.foo();`

`<button onclick='parent.test();'>test</button>` **works** now... `top.test()` works too, **BUT**, I'd like a way to normalize this. Its not very intuitive.

Is there a way to NOT have to prefix `top.` or `parent.`?

Comment: @Huangism Test() is defined in the iFrame as the OP screenshot suggests. Now, I'm just trying to figure out why i need to use a prefix for the function wot work... weird.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the jQuery library is being called before any other script inside your `<head>` section.

Most of the times I get this error, I just change the order the scripts being called on the page (always under jQuery) and it solves the problem.

Comment: The OP is not using jQuery.

Comment: I do use jQuery, but that should be outside the scope of this simple example.

Comment: I mentioned jQuery because I get this exact same error very often, and simply reordering the scritps libraries solves the problem. Even when the error doesn't use jQuery, it can conflict.

Comment: I got it to work as noted in the above comment, but I want to have the need for prefixing `top` or `parent` for all `js` calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but I'll share my solution.

I needed an iframe as a preview container. So parent.something would be a hassle.

This seems to work:

```
<iframe id='iframe' sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

And populate it with this (example using jquery):

```
$(function() {

    let $iframe = $('#iframe');
    $iframe.ready(function() {

       let ifhead = `
       <meta charset="UTF-8"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"><\/script>`;
       let ifbody = `<h1>My Body</h1>`;
       let ifscript = `$(function() { $('h1').css('color', 'blue')})`;
       let html = `<html><head>${ifhead}</head><body>${ifbody}<script>${ifscript}<\/script></body></html>`; 


       document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.open();
       document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.write(html);
       document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.close();

    });

});
```

Now the iframe acts as a stand-alone page.